# Authentication for REST API?

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication, authorization

I am a complete beginner, and have just started learning about web development. Now I am asking myself some questions regards REST API: Does it make sense to secure a REST API with authentication? If so, what are the common ways of doing this?

I am under the impression that REST API's are precisely there because we try to enable many different users to access them. Now I would like to write a small application which makes requests to a node.js server and gets some stuff back. All via REST API.

However, I do not want others to be able to make similar requests to that server though. How would I best secure this? Am I misunderstanding something big time here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not authenticating the REST APIs means you are allowing everybody to hit your REST endpoints. It is a better practise to authenticate REST APIs and allow only certain users to access the APIs. The [link](https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/) might help you to have a start.

Answer (score 0):

It is super simple: when you provide a *service*, most likely, you only want to allow certain, *authenticated* users to call that service. In other words: it is possible to have rest services that work without any kind of authentication - but is rather the exception,  not the rule.

The more common approach is that, say a hotel only allows people with a key to enter rooms. Same story for services ...

And there are many ways to do that, see [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-9f811a92bb52) for a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is important for REST APIs because you only want certain users to access your data via GET api and/or be able to make modifications to your database via POST api.
[JSON Web Tokens(JWT)](https://jwt.io/introduction/) is the most commonly used authentication framework. Here's a [very basic tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens) about how to authenticate node js API with JWT.